# Text-overflow: ellipsis causes flex item to overflow flex container

Tags: html, css, flexbox, ellipsis

I have two columns inside a flex container. One of the columns (orange one) contains an avatar and its width should be exactly 10% of container.

Another column (blue one) contains panel, and the panel's title could be very long, so I should truncate it via css. This picture shows what I expect:

What I expect:

[image: What I expect]

But when I'm trying to do `text-overflow: ellipsis`, my second row is becoming wider than the flex container. Here is example of this behaviour:

https://jsfiddle.net/8krtL9ev/1/

```css
.container {
  background: #ddd;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
}

.row1 {
  background: red;
  flex-basis: 10%;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.row2 {
  background: blue;
  flex-basis: 90%;
  margin-left: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
}

.panel {
  background: green;
  flex-basis: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.panel-title {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="row1">
  </div>

  <div class="row2">
    <div class="panel">
      <div class="panel-title">
        <span>Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum.</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: All you need is `min-width: 0` on `.row2` ([revised fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8krtL9ev/5/)). See the duplicate for an explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `width` in place of `flex-basis`. Because in [this Documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#intrinsic-item-contributions) they have mentioned

> 9.9.3. Flex Item Intrinsic Size Contributions
>
> The main-size min-content/max-content contribution of a flex item is
>   its outer min-content/max-content size, clamped by its flex base size
>   as a maximum (if it is not growable) and/or as a minimum (if it is not
>   shrinkable), and then further clamped by its min/max main size
>   properties.

Don't forget to set width `calc(90% - 30px)` as `row2` width

```css
.container {
  background: #ddd;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
}

.row1 {
    background: red;
    /* flex-basis: 10%; */
    width: 10%;
    flex-shrink: 0;
}

.row2 {
    background: blue;
    /* flex-basis: 90%; */
    width: calc(90% - 30px);
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    display: flex;
}

.panel {
  background: green;
  flex-basis: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.panel-title {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="row1">
  </div>

  <div class="row2">
    <div class="panel">
      <div class="panel-title">
        <span>Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum.</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @user3735215 Yaah, I have added the explaination

Comment: This answer is overkill. The blue box is overflowing the container because the default minimum size of flex items is `min-width: auto` (content length). All that is needed to fix the problem is to override the default with `min-width: 0` or `overflow: hidden` on `.row2`.